# Is there any way to read json data in dynamic way?

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3

I have different type of JSON files.
For Example, 1 File has JSON like this,

```
{
   "first":true,
   "last":true,
   "pageSize":10,
   "page":0,
   "totalPages":1,
   "totalItems":10,
   "items":[
      {
         "chargerId":"EX-1193-1A13-1-2149-00024",
         "chargerName":"Lite-on IC80",
         "imsi":null,
         "location":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -84.62403006,
               39.13444449
            ]
         },
        "MD_BATCH_ID": "253",
        "MD_INGESTION_DATE_TIME": "2022-12-21 14:37:07.223291",
        "MD_RECORD_NUMBER": 2
      },
      {
         "chargerId":"0df6d6930f494a2e86f5aa4d5fdf78fc",
         "chargerName":"Solution Lab Rhombus 60kW",
         "imsi":null,
         "location":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -84.62248500,
               39.13479400
            ]
         },
        "MD_BATCH_ID": "253",
        "MD_INGESTION_DATE_TIME": "2022-12-21 14:37:07.223291",
        "MD_RECORD_NUMBER": 2
      }
   ]
}
```

2. Second JSON file looks like this,

```
[
    {
        "assetId": "2ca0021f841adc4b01841ae581730000",
        "start": "2022-09-23T15:04:34.229Z",
        "end": "2050-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "year": 2022,
        "oem": "FORD",
        "model": "F-150",
        "MD_BATCH_ID": "253",
        "MD_INGESTION_DATE_TIME": "2022-12-21 14:37:07.223291",
        "MD_RECORD_NUMBER": 2

    },
    {
        "assetId": "2ca0075582044cdc0182371cb4da0004",
        "start": "2022-01-04T17:24:39.809Z",
        "end": "2050-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "year": 2022,
        "oem": "KIA",
        "model": "Niro",
        "MD_BATCH_ID": "253",
        "MD_INGESTION_DATE_TIME": "2022-12-21 14:37:07.223291",
        "MD_RECORD_NUMBER": 2
    }
]
```

Now I have to add some key value pairs in both files but i don't know which type of JSON i will receive because in the first JSON object the data is inside **items** whereas in the second JSON the data is directly available without any key.

I want to make it dynamic so that I can append key and values in the object regardless of what file I am receiving in Python. If you see above, I have added 3 keys in each element MD_BATCH_ID,MD_INGESTION_DATE_TIME,MD_RECORD_NUMBER. I have to add these 3 keys to each element inside JSON object. How can i make it dynamic? Please help.

Currently, My code looks like this but it will not work for every file, This will only work for files that have items as key -

```
def process_json_file(json_string,s3_client,bucket_name,key):
    global index_count
    index_count = 1 
    print('Inside Json Reader')
    json_content = json.loads(json_string)
    cur_datetime = datetime.now()
    print(json_content['items'])
    for i in json_content['items']:
        i["MD_BATCH_ID"] = '253'
        i["MD_INGESTION_DATE_TIME"] = cur_datetime
        i["MD_RECORD_NUMBER"] = index_count
        index_count = index_count +1 
    s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key, Body=json.dumps(json_content,indent=4,default=str).encode())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if your `json_content` contains your items array.

`json_content.__contains__('items')`

If it doesn't, you can add it by doing:

`json_content.append({ 'items' : [{'Column1':'Data for your column'}]})`

The magic method `__contains__` helps a lot to find what is missing, than you can add (by appending), dealing with all your data.

Hope that's what you looking for.

#### Improved answer:

I've created your code and two files: Test0.json and Test1.Json, with your sample Jsons.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import json

def process_json_file(json_content,s3_client,bucket_name,key):
    global index_count
    index_count = 1 
    print('Inside Json Reader')
    cur_datetime = datetime.now()
    for ix, value in enumerate(json_content):
        print (value)
        if(type(value) == type({})): #If type is a dictionary, you have another object inside.
            #Create a recursive call if you want several levels
            for jx, val in enumerate(value):
                print(val)
        
    
    if(json_content.__contains__('items')):
        for i in json_content['items']:
            i["MD_BATCH_ID"] = '253'
            i["MD_INGESTION_DATE_TIME"] = cur_datetime
            i["MD_RECORD_NUMBER"] = index_count
            index_count = index_count +1 
    #s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key, Body=json.dumps(json_content,indent=4,default=str).encode())

with open("Test0.json") as json_file:
    defaultValues = json.load(json_file)
    process_json_file(defaultValues, None,None,None)

with open("Test1.json") as json_file:
    defaultValues = json.load(json_file)
    process_json_file(defaultValues, None,None,None)
```

When you import your file and transform it as Json, you will get several objects whitin it. So it's possible to enumerate them, travelling inside, changing/adding stuff. Check if you can enumerate your objects:
[How to check whether a json object is array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304835/how-to-check-whether-a-json-object-is-array)

Then you'll be able to compare and add things at your will. Just remmeber to compare and find the sweat spots where your need data will be inserted.

If that's what you looking for, please remmeber marking as answer :)

Comment: But if the next file has some other word than 'items' then also it will not work right?

Comment: I'm assuming that you're running over files and sending the files content to your funcion: ```process_json_file```, so inside this function you'll need to check if your content has the key: "items".

Comment: Yes I can check that but the issue is the keywords 'items' is not constant. It can change.
I need to pull the top level array.

Comment: I've improved the answer. Please check if that helps you. Also, put some breakpoints in the code I've just sent you, so you can see how things are moving inside.